# How to have multiple anchor targets on a single element using Skrollr?

Tags: javascript, html, css, skrollr

Is it possible to have multiple anchor targets for a single element with Skrollr? For example, I need something like the following:

```
<section id="main-slide"
                 data-start="background-color:rgb(255,255,255);"
                 data-top-top="background-color:rgb(255,0,0);"
                 data-anchor-target="#slide1"

                 data-top-top="background-color:rgb(255,0,0);"
                 data-bottom-top="background-color:rgb(0,255,0);"
                 data-anchor-target="#slide2">
```

And so, it's like I have the first set of scroll animation relative to `#slide1`, and then as I continue to scroll, I should trigger the second set of scroll animation relative to `#slide2`.

I've tried the code above, but it didn't get Skrollr to work correctly.

How can I have multiple anchor targets?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible - you are initialising the same attributes twice (data-top-top & data-anchor-top). You could try using [skrollr keyframing](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr#keyframe) to pipe events from #slide1 & #slide2 to your own event handler.